# Get the index of checked input by input name

Tags: jquery

I have 2 `name`s of inputs (`group1` and `group2`). How can I get the index of the checked box given one of those `name`s?

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked>
```

For example, if I check the second radio box in `group2` ("Beer") it will return 2.

Edit: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vtGay/3/) based on feedback; still not working.

Comment: what is the need for u to get that index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Almost all other answers is about **index()**, but in your case the second radio buttons index() would not return 2 like you wanted, **it would return 1** as the index is 0 based.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtGay/5/) shows how you can get the *index / value / score / number* of a selected input in a specific group, and how you can sum up values from all selected radio buttons.

```
<form id="myForm">
     <h3>First Group</h3>

    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="the-first" data-points="0">First</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="the-second" data-points="20">Second</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="the-third" data-points="300">Third</input>
    <hr>
    <h3>Second Group</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="four" data-points="4">4</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="five" data-points="5">5</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="six" data-points="6">6</input>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and the javascript/jQuery (using alert instead of console.log for demonstrative purposes) :

```
$(function () {
    $("#myForm").submit(function () {
        //This gets the checked input in group1
        var g1 = $("input[name='group1']:checked");
        alert("Group 1 \n Selected Value: " + g1.val() + " \n Selected Index: " + g1.index() + "\n Points: " + g1.data('points'));

        var totalPoints = 0;

        //This loops through all checked inputs
        $.each($("input:checked"), function () {
            totalPoints += $(this).data("points");
        });

        alert("Total points from all groups: " + totalPoints);

        return false; //remove if you want to submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find the checked element for each group, then find it's index. Make sure to filter inside the `index()` function, otherwise it will give the index among all siblings, not just the inputs for that group.

```
var group1Index = $('input[name="group1"]:checked').index('input[name="group1"]');
var group2Index = $('input[name="group2"]:checked').index('input[name="group2"]');
```

**EDIT** Note the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function is 0 indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to loop over the buttons, and return the one that is checked:

```
function getRadioValue(RadioName)
{
var colRadio = document.getElementsByName(RadioName);
for (var i = 0; i < colRadio.length; i++)
{
if (colRadio[i].checked)
{
return colRadio[i].value;
}
return null;
}

vValue = getRadioValue("group1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the 0 based index of checked input element named "group1"

```
$('input[name="group1"]:checked').index()
```

Comment: Did what you said man but nothing prints in id="result" :
http://jsfiddle.net/vtGay/3/

Comment: I made an exemple, it shows how to get selected index and / or value of a given radio button group : http://jsfiddle.net/ZTxUA/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();
    // do whatever with the index
  });
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/isovil/1/edit)

In the above code (and the presented example) it is important that the checkboxes are grouped in a container that only contains them, since `index` returns a number representing the index of the element regarding its container.